# Httpclient cannot read json locally or on server

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am in using the `HttpClient` module built into angular 7 to read a JSON from a server. When using the `HttpClient` it always returns

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at push../src/app/info/info.component.ts.info.getVars (info.component.ts:37)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:498)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
>       at timer (zone.js:2281)

I thought that this meant that the JSON couldn't be found/or was blank.

I have tried to read the JSON from the server (no success) and I have put the JSON into the assets folder to read it and I get the same error. I know that it should work in the assets folder because I can import it from the assets folder with no problem:
 `import infoJson from '../../assets/info.json`

This is what I have currently tried: (**.component.ts**)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

export class VehicleinfoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient ) { }

    getVars() {
        this.httpService.get('../../assets/info.json').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
        })
      }
}
```

I have also tried creating a service, but I get the same error: (**.service.ts**):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetJsonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getJsonInfo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./assets/info.json')
  }
}
```

**.component.ts**:

```
import { GetJsonService } from '../get-json.service'

export class VehicleinfoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private GetJson: GetJsonService) { }

    getVars() {
        this.GetJson.getJsonInfo().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to use `HttpClient` is because the JSON automatically updates with new data and I want to be able to read and display this.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
This is an example of the JSON I am trying to read:

```
{
    "playerdata": [
        {
            "USER_ID": "7a8f",
            "Status": 1,
            "Start_Time": "2016-12-21 09:41:57",
            "Finish_Time": "2016-12-21 09:43:17",
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, this is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //components declared
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    //other imports here
  ],
  providers: [  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It would seem as if httpClient is undefines. Try `console.log(this.httpClient)`

Comment: @jared This is what I get: `HttpClient(handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }`

Comment: is your json in correct format? Can you attach a snippet of that as well.

Comment: Make sure you import HttpClientModule in your module

Comment: @MuhammadKamran added snippet of json to the question

Comment: @Jojofoulk if it wasn't imported the error would read "No provider for HttpClient !"

Comment: @JackU please provide a [mcve] of your issue. And at least the trace of the error.

Comment: @JackU, I have added a stckblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dscwsc which has the http get method in ```app.component.ts``` and calls external api and working fine as well.. May i know what your actual problem then??

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur I used your stackblitz in my code and it seems to work. When trying to get the json from the server I get `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` (When i use the API in the stackblitz it work perfectly . So i will look into this now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wait, how are you creating your VehicleinfoComponent?? Is it created by angular from template?

Answer (score -2):

`this.httpService`
here `httpService` is `undefined` meaning that injection did not happen.

Double check your module configuration if you have proper providers declared (and it it s working if custom made).

Propert import should look like this:

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, // HERE
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: If that was the case, the error would say `No provider for HttpClient !`

Comment: Just added what my `app.module.ts` looks like. Looks the same as this.